# execute code after callback function finish

Tags: javascript, typescript

i want to execute addFormLayoutSectionFieldsView() function after all callback finish in this code Ts file

````
webPart._getListDataSources(xComp).then((response) => {
            let dItems: List_Item[] = response.value;
            dItems.forEach((item: List_Item) => {
              dataSourceId = item["Id"];
              webPart._getListDataSourceFieldsData(dataSourceId).then((response) => {
                let pItems: List_Item[] = response.value;
                pItems.forEach((item: List_Item) => {
                  AddSectionFieldHtml1 += `<option value= "${item["Id"]}"> ${item["Id"]} </option>`;
                  console.log(AddSectionFieldHtml1);
                });
              });
            });
          });
            
webPart.addFormLayoutSectionFieldsView(FormLayoutSectionId);```
````

Comment: So why not put that code after the last statement of the innermost `then(` callback?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I've always used `Promise.all` alongside `map`

````
webPart._getListDataSources(xComp).then((response) => {
            Promise.all(response.value.map((item: List_Item) => {
              dataSourceId = item["Id"];
              return webPart._getListDataSourceFieldsData(dataSourceId).then((response) => {
                let pItems: List_Item[] = response.value;
                pItems.forEach((item: List_Item) => {
                  AddSectionFieldHtml1 += `<option value= "${item["Id"]}"> ${item["Id"]} </option>`;
                  console.log(AddSectionFieldHtml1);
                });
              });
            });
          })).then(() =>             
            webPart.addFormLayoutSectionFieldsView(FormLayoutSectionId);
          )```
````

So here instead of just iterating over all the items and doing new async calls, you are turning each item into a promise, collecting that array of promises with `Promise.all`, and then when all promises are finished, executing the callback passed to the `Promise.all(...).then`.

For example,

```
Promise
  .all([1,2].map(Promise.resolve)
  .then(() => console.log('Done with promises!'))
```

That will turn `1` and `2` into promises, and then when both resolve, the console will get logged to.

Comment: I tried it and AddSectionFieldHtml1  return empty string even it should have many lines

Comment: It should not have many lines based on the code you provided.

Comment: If it should be a collector of all teh data from those for loops,above `webPart._getListDataSources` put `let AddSectionFieldHtml1 = ''`

Comment: Every `pItems.forEach` you are initializing a brand new `AddSectionFieldHtml1` as undefined and then assigning a single <option> string to it. Then when that `forEach` block terminates, the value vanishes into thin air. So if you're executing all of that code and then trying to access the data, yes, it's going to be undefined (not an empty string) rather than a multiline string.

Comment: i declare `AddSectionFieldHtml1 ` global so i can use it in `addFormLayoutSectionFieldsView()`